# Define header, footer, navigation, main, etc in qooxdoo standalone application

Tags: qooxdoo

Im taking my very first steps using qooxdoo, and I would like to create a layout having those areas to insert some widgets into them. Im trying to achieve something like this : http://w2ui.com/web/demo/layout
Im confused about wich widget is best to get it done.
Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I kept digging the manual/api I found something to get it done. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

check the example.
regards

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520tabView%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.TabView()%253B%250D%250Avar%2520page%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(%2522Page%2522)%253B%250D%250Apage.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250AtabView.add(page)%253B%250D%250Athis.getRoot().add(tabView%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A10%252C%2520top%253A10%252C%2520right%253A%252010%252C%2520bottom%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520desktop%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Desktop()%253B%250D%250Apage.add(desktop%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520%252210%2525%2522%252C%2520top%253A%2520%252210%2525%2522%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%2520%252210%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520header%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow())%253B%250D%250Aheader.add(new%2520qx.ui.form.TextArea().set(%257Bvalue%253A%2520%2522header%2522%257D))%253B%250D%250Apage.add(header%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%2520%252290%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520footer%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow())%253B%250D%250Afooter.add(new%2520qx.ui.form.TextArea().set(%257Bvalue%253A%2520%2522footer%2522%257D))%253B%250D%250Apage.add(footer%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%2520%252290%2525%2522%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520left%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow())%253B%250D%250Aleft.add(new%2520qx.ui.form.TextArea().set(%257Bvalue%253A%2520%2522left%2522%257D))%253B%250D%250Apage.add(left%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%2520%252210%2525%2522%252C%2520right%253A%2520%252290%2525%2522%252C%2520bottom%253A%2520%252210%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window(%2522window%2522).set(%257Bwidth%253A%2520200%252C%2520height%253A%2520200%257D)%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(win)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Open%2520window%2522)%253B%250D%250Abtn.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520win.center()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520win.open()%253B%2520%2520%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(btn%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520200%252C%2520top%253A%2520200%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)